# Bicubic Image Interpolation Algorithm - Glitches

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics

I am trying to implement bicubic image interpolation. I have only pasted relevant sections of the code. I have skipped the code dealing with loading the image into a buffer and reading pixels from them etc. I am reasonably sure my math is correct. However, I seem to be having terrible artifacts in the output.

All the action happens in the resize method.

Am hoping that experienced graphics programmers may be able to share their hunches as to what I could be doing wrong.

The following are the input and output images that I get when resizing the input to twice its width and height.

[image: input image]
[image: output image]

```
double Interpolator::interpolate(const double p0, const double p1, const double p2, const double p3, const double x){
    return  (-0.5f*p0+1.5f*p1-1.5f*p2+0.5*p3)*pow(x,3)+
            (p0-2.5f*p1+2.f*p2-0.5f*p3)*pow(x,2)+
            (-0.5f*p0+0.5f*p2)*x+
            p1;
}

bool Image::equals(double a, double b, double threshold){
        if(fabs(a-b)<=threshold)
            return true;
        return false;
}


void Image::interpolate(const Pixel p[], double offset, Pixel& result){
    result.r = Interpolator::interpolate(p[0].r,p[1].r,p[2].r,p[3].r,offset);
    result.g = Interpolator::interpolate(p[0].g,p[1].g,p[2].g,p[3].g,offset);
    result.b = Interpolator::interpolate(p[0].b,p[1].b,p[2].b,p[3].b,offset);
    result.a = Interpolator::interpolate(p[0].a,p[1].a,p[2].a,p[3].a,offset);   
}

void Image::getSamplingCoords(const int nearest,
                              const int max,
                              int coords[]){

    coords[0] = nearest-1;
    if(coords[0]<0)
        coords[0] = nearest;
    coords[1] = nearest;
    coords[2] = nearest+1;
    if(coords[2]>=max)
        coords[2] = nearest;    
    coords[3] = nearest+2;
    //The following check should not be necessary
    //since this is never expected to occur. Nevertheless...
    if(coords[3]>=max)
        coords[3] = nearest;
}

void Image::interpolateAlongY(int x, int y, int yMax, double yOffset, Pixel& result){

    if(equals(yOffset,0.f,ERROR_THRESHOLD)){
        //No interpolation required
        getPixel(x,y,result);
        return;
    }

    int yCoords[4];
    getSamplingCoords(y, yMax, yCoords);    
    Pixel interpolants[4];
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
        getPixel(x, yCoords[i], interpolants[i]);
    }   
    interpolate(interpolants, y, result);
}

void Image::resize(const int newWidth, const int newHeight){
    //Ensure that we have a valid buffer already
    if(buffer==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Must load an image before resizing it!");
        assert(false);
    }   
    //We first need to create a new buffer with the new dimensions
    unsigned char* newBuffer = new unsigned char[newWidth*newHeight*channelCount];
    for(int j=0; j<newHeight; ++j){
        for(int i=0; i<newWidth; ++i){
            size_t newIndexOffset = (j*newWidth+i)*channelCount;
            //For this pixel in the target image we
            //a) Find the nearest pixel in the source image
            //b) Find the offset from the aforementioned nearest pixel
            int xNear,yNear;
            double xOffset,yOffset;
            double x = ((double)width/(double)newWidth)*i;
            double y = ((double)height/(double)newHeight)*j;    
            xNear = floor(x);
            yNear = floor(y);   
            xOffset = x-xNear;
            yOffset = y-yNear;

            //If offset is 0, we don't need any interpolation
            //we simply need to sample the source pixel and proceed
//          if(equals(xOffset,0.f,ERROR_THRESHOLD) && equals(yOffset,0.f,ERROR_THRESHOLD)){
//              Pixel result;
//              getPixel(xNear, yNear, result);
//              *(newBuffer+newIndexOffset) = result.r;
//              *(newBuffer+newIndexOffset+1) = result.g;
//              *(newBuffer+newIndexOffset+2) = result.b;
//              if(channelCount==4)
//                  *(buffer+newIndexOffset+3) = result.a;
//              continue;
//          }           
            //We make a check that xNear and yNear obtained above
            //are always smaller than the edge pixels at the extremeties
            if(xNear>=width || yNear>=height){
                printf("ERROR: Nearest pixel computation error!");
                assert(false);
            }           
            //Next we find four pixels along the x direction around this
            //nearest pixel
            int xCoords[4];
            getSamplingCoords(xNear,width,xCoords);

            //For each of these sampling xCoords, we interpolate 4 nearest points
            //along Y direction
            Pixel yInterps[4];
            for(int k=0; k<4; k++){
                interpolateAlongY(xCoords[k], yNear, height, yOffset, yInterps[k]);
            }           
            //Finally, the resultant pixel is a cubic interpolation
            //on the 4 obtained pixels above
            Pixel result;
            if(equals(xOffset,0.f,ERROR_THRESHOLD)){
                result.r = yInterps[0].r;
                result.g = yInterps[0].g;
                result.b = yInterps[0].b;
                result.a = yInterps[0].a;
            }else{
                interpolate(yInterps, xOffset, result);
            }
            *(newBuffer+newIndexOffset) = result.r;
            *(newBuffer+newIndexOffset+1) = result.g;
            *(newBuffer+newIndexOffset+2) = result.b;
            if(channelCount==4)
                *(newBuffer+newIndexOffset+3) = result.a;
        }   
    }   
    //Now we can deallocate the memory of our current buffer
    delete [] buffer;
    //Reassign our newly sampled buffer to our own
    buffer = newBuffer;
    //Reset our image dimensions
    height = newHeight;
    width = newWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`interpolateAlongY` is wrong, the last line is

```
interpolate(interpolants, y, result);
```

and should be

```
interpolate(interpolants, yOffset, result);
```

Additionally the comment in `getSamplingCoords` for `coords[3]` is wrong.

Edit:

After I looked through JansonD's answer I noticed two more problems, the excepetions with `if(equals(xOffset,0.f,ERROR_THRESHOLD))` are not even necessary, the interpolation function does the right thing when the value of the offset is close to 0.

The other thing is, that your interpolation function is probably a lowpass filter as you add information from the neighboring pixels, so you are probably loosing detail on high frequency data like edges.

Comment: Wow! I am quite embarrassed for not catching that! Thanks a ton! That fixed the problem. It is indeed at the offset that the interpolation ought to have been done.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Josef's answer regarding:

```
interpolate(interpolants, y, result);
```

Needing to reference `yOffset`, there is also:

```
if(equals(xOffset,0.f,ERROR_THRESHOLD)){
            result.r = yInterps[0].r;
            result.g = yInterps[0].g;
            result.b = yInterps[0].b;
            result.a = yInterps[0].a;
```

Which should use `yInterps[1]`.

Also none of the output values are clamped, so there may be underflow and overflow around sharp edges.

And the comment for:

```
if(coords[3]>=max)
    coords[3] = nearest;
```

Isn't the only thing wrong, but indeed the clamp should be to `max-1`, and not `nearest`, unless you mean to reflect the edge pixels rather than repeat them.